# How can I get counts of related items in RavenDb?

Tags: c#, ravendb

In RavenDb, I am trying to get a list of items that include counts.

Using the Raven sample DB as a simplified example, I would like to get a list of categories with the count of products in each category.

### Relevant classes:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    // ...others removed...
}
```

### Partially working query (but misses 0 counts)

The following query seems to work (I am using `.Dump();` for Linqpad):

```
using (var session = docStore.OpenSession()) {
    var products = session
        .Query<Product>()
        .Customize(x => x.Include<Product>(p => p.Category))
        .ToArray() 
        .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(x => new {
            category = session.Load<Category>(x.Key), 
            numProducts = x.Count()
        })
        .Dump();

    session.Advanced.NumberOfRequests.Dump("NumberOfRequests");
}
```

[image]

The problem with this is if there is a category with no products, it is not included in the result set.

(Also, is this the correct way to perform this query? One request to the server hints to me I'm at least not *horrendously* off track)

### Correct results using very bad query

Resorting to brute force, I can use the code:

```
using (var session = docStore.OpenSession()) {
    var categories = session
        .Query<Category>();

    var categoryCounts = new Dictionary<Category,int>();
    foreach (var category in categories) 
    {
        if (!categoryCounts.ContainsKey(category)) categoryCounts.Add(category,0);
        categoryCounts[category] += session
            .Query<Product>()
            .Where(p => p.Category == category.Id)
            .Count();
    }
    categoryCounts.Dump();

    session.Advanced.NumberOfRequests.Dump("NumberOfRequests");
}
```

[image]

But this is obviously a terrible way, resulting in 1+n requests (where n == number of categories).

---

How can I get the category + number of products, including categories with no products, and do so without causing 1+n requests?

Are the different considerations for a database with hundreds of categories and hundreds of thousands (or even millions) of products (where a single category alone could have hundreds of thousands)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customary way to do something like this is by using an index (i.e. a map - reduce index). I haven't thoroughly thought this though, so there may be easier ways to achieve this than using a multi map, but I think you can do the following:

```
public class CategoryUsageCount
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int UsageCount { get; set; }
}

public class UsageCountByCategory : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<CategoryUsageCount>
{
    public UsageCountByCategory()
    {
        AddMap<Category>(categories => 
            from category in categories 
            select new {
                CategoryId = category.Id,
                Category = category,
                UsageCount = 0
            });

        AddMap<Procuct>(products =>
            from product in products
            select new {
                CategoryId = product.Category,
                Category = (Category)null,
                UsageCount = 1
            });

        Reduce = results => 
            from result in results
            group result by result.CategoryId into g
            select new {
                CategoryId = g.Key,
                Category = g.First(x => x != null).Category,
                UsageCount = g.Sum(x => x.UsageCount)
            };

        Index(x => x.CategoryId, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
using (var session = docStore.OpenSession()) {
    var categoryUsageCounts = session
        .Query<CategoryUsageCount, UsageCountByCategory>()
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: So this worked great, and helped teach me a lot, so thanks! In my use though, I realized a major drawback: I was using this as the main list for editing my 'category' objects.. but there are times when the index is stale and then all the categories aren't displayed (maybe just a problem after deploying index, but I'm not sure). I ended up using a simpler Map-Reduce index to count Products, then did a `Query<Categories>()` using client-side LINQ to left-join the index `Query<ProductsCounts,Products_ByCategory>()`. Two requests to server, but it means for sure I always get all categories.

Comment: Yes with RavenDB, you do need to let go of  a few of your traditional database world views. Indexes are eventually consistent by default. It is possible to get non-stale results, by customizing the query and specifying it needs to [wait  for non-stale results](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.0/csharp/client-api/querying/stale-indexes). However you may want to review your design (i.e. models and their relationships), to see if denormalizing your models along transaction boundaries and materialized views might lead to better solutions.